# Can one use categories to mock UI instances in iOS Testing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, mocking

My idea is to create a category of `UIActionSheet` in order to be able to mock the different possible user interactions (select item / cancel) and to check the correct initialization.

I was hoping that by importing the category that I created into my test, all farther usages of `UIActionSheet` are going to be through that category, but it's not the case. Has anyone had similar experience? What other ways do you suggest to do UI mocking?

```
@interface UIActionSheet (LMActionSheetMonkey)
    bla bla
@end
```

Another idea is to import the category in the class using `#ifdef TESTAPP`, but i'm trying to affect my actual implementation for the sake of testing.

Comment: Why don't you use OCMocks?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this, especially if you combine it with a bit of swizzling. I have recently done this.

EDIT - the below bit is no longer true.

*I used to use OCMock, but it doesn't work properly with ARC and weak references:
http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2012/03/26/weak-references-to-nsproxy-with-arc/
because of an iOS bug whereby a weak reference to an NSProxy is always nil
[Why is my object's weak delegate property nil in my unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675054/why-is-my-objects-weak-delegate-property-nil-in-my-unit-tests)*

Comment: Swizzling is the method that I tried to use, but the swizzled implementation is not picked up in the test*ed* class.

Comment: Apple fixed the weak reference to NSProxy instances bug a while ago, with iOS 6, I'm pretty sure.  It has not been an issue for a while.

Comment: @Carl thanks - I ran a test project just now and it is definitely fixed; implies I have a separate problem with OCMock I need to investigate further.